# Can OSGi bundles register Swing lnfs as services?

Tags: osgi

Can I register Swing look and feels from OSGi bundles as services so that the installed or future bundles can use these services(lnfs) and update their frame look and feel at runtime ? I want to make Swing lnfs pluggable so that they can be installed/removed into/from a running program with bundles exporting them.

Are there any limitations or necessary steps or cautions or tips to this approach ?

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Unrelated note: if you're looking for a RCP for Swing, then have a look at the NetBeans Platform. It uses a custom module system by default (not OSGi, but similar). Maybe there is some support for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can register any object as an OSGi service. Registering a service is covered in every OSGi tutorial, simply google it (also SO as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974271/registering-a-service-and-looking-for-the-service)).

Why do you choose OSGi with Swing setup? This is a supported combination but not that common, most people developing OSGi stick to SWT/JFace. Do you already have a Swing codebase that you want to use in an OSGi container?

Comment: I do not want to loose the flexibility Swing provides. So far I have never seen a GUI framework, other than Swing , that gives the flexibility Swing provides. Please let me know if such frameworks exist. I do  not know about SWT. In addition my application needs PDF renderers developed in Java.

Comment: Just google for java GUI frameworks. Answering comprehensively the question requires duplicating a lot of stuff that's easily accessible on the web. Most of the frameworks work in OSGi environment and the most popular in OSGi is SWT/JFace.